# Customizing { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements' as per below image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I'm trying to change the styling of searchbar using 'react-native-elements', fuctionality wise it's working but for styling, I'm facing some issues

My Image
[image]

Expected Image
[image]

My Code:

```
            <SearchBar
              //searchIcon={{ size: 24 }}
              onChangeText={text => this.testFilter(text)}
              onClear={text => this.testFilter('')}
              inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
              containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', borderWidth: 0, marginLeft: 50 }}
              inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
              placeholderTextColor={'#g5g5g5'}
              placeholder={'Search...'}
              clearIcon={false}
              searchIcon={false}
              value={this.state.test}
            />
```

How can I achieve the same styling using the Searchbar component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to meet the requirement after making some changes with some logics and stylings

Comment: Please add details about *what* styling and logic changes were needed to answer this question for others that come across it

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding `inputContainerStyle` prop like this?

```
inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
```

you also should look at `searchIcon` and `cancelIcon` props to restyle the icons used in the default `SearchBar` component.

Comment: Yes, already added earlier, you can see my updated code, I'm stuck with the back arrow which will close the search and the box shadow below the entire wide